# Creating new folder from new names entered in text file

Tags: python

How can you update/ create new folders every time you enter a new name of the text file in python script?

```
import os

with open('Clients.txt')as x:
    for line in x:
       line = line.strip()
       os.mkdir(str(line))
```

Comment: Please properly format your code, it makes understanding the question easier. Secondly, is your script not working for some reason, do you get an error?

Comment: this is working. it did creates folder from the text file. what i want to do is, everytime i will enter a new name from the text file. it should be creating a folder at the same time. And that I don't know what script should i add on this one I provided.

Comment: There are ways to monitor file system activity, and reread the file.  For this application it would be simpler to just periodically open the file, read it, compare it to your previous read, and create any new directories.

Comment: You might want to check os.path.exists() which will tell you if a file/folder exists and if it doesn't create it